# Calling another language with MQL5

Tags: c#, php, python, r, mql5

I would like to scan an economic calendar (and in a second step possibly a news source) like [this one](https://www.dailyfx.com/deutsch/wirtschaftsdatenkalender?tz=%2B1.0&sort=date&week=2017%2F0205&eur=true&usd=true&jpy=true&gbp=true&chf=true&aud=true&cad=true&nzd=true&cny=true&high=true&medium=true&low=false) for use in MetaTrader/MQL5. I guess I would need another programming language than MQL5 for that, possibly (but not necessarily) C#? (How) can it be done in principle?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether you can access that web page through WebRequest() function available in MT4/5. Alternative way is to write a DLL (or to find one) and access the link above through the REST api (but it doesnt make sense as WebRequest provides it) or somehow else. The easiest way is to check all calendars you may find (myfxbook, mt5.com, fxfactory) and find the easiest page to parse with MT5 methods, then try to collect data and process it. If your skills include some other languages, it might make sense to collect data with REST and then parse it with Jsoup/soup/beautiful-soup (the library that is designed for your language) - that will help with tests (to clear the data faster), and WebRequest() for live.